# C - Input testing for ctrl + character

Tags: c, input, comparison, control-characters

Was wondering how you would be able to test the input that is saved in an char array like...

```
   char input[INPUT_SIZE];
```

And using

```
fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin);
```

To get the input from the user but was wondering how i could use a if statement to test if the users input has been for example
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> or any <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  anykey?

I tryed using there ascci value like this.. is an example to test for ctrl d

```
  if(result = 'EOT') {printf("EOT");}
```

Result is a char array aswell.

Comment: You're thinking along the right lines, but `'EOT'` is not the ASCII value of Ctrl-D (you're looking for 4). Your example won't compile, or at the very least give a warning.

Comment: so should i test it for result = 4?

Comment: The line `if(result = 'EOT')` is wrong in so many ways in C.

Comment: How would you rephrase it then?

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator, and `'EOT'` is not a `char`. Also read the documentation for `fgets` to see what exactly it stores in the buffer and when it stops reading. The ASCII value for EOT is 4, try and run [this code](http://ideone.com/46ltl) and see if 4 comes up in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only test <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> as your read returning `EOF`, see the manual of your read to have more info on this, but generally it returns 0. Same goes for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, as both are sending signals to your program.

For other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+key combinations, it highly depends on your system.

On linux <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> in a shell or emacs will move you to the beginning or the end / beginning of the line respectively.

The easiest to get what you want is to write a small program using read, unbuffered (see [ioctl](http://www.linux-kheops.com/doc/man/manfr/man-html-0.9/man2/ioctl.2.html)), with a 8-bytes buffer, and dump your read bytes each time you exit the read.

```
int nbr;
int i;
char buf[8];

nbr = 42;
while (nbr > 0)
{
  nbr = read(0, buf, 8);
  i = 0;
  while (i < nbr)
    printf("%x ", buf[i++]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

You will have the hex version of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+key received sequences. Likely to begin with \ESC or \033 (the escape character sequence). For example the arrow-up key looks like `\033[A`